# Some footer issues I'm having

Tags: html, css, footer

So I reset my grid layout on a temporary practice page, though not entirely since this page's layout is extremely similar to the home page (the previous page I styled). Though, immediately I started having problems with the footer. It appears beside the content part and seems to stick there [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l3pu.png), no matter what I do.

The only thing that works is putting `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`. This does force the footer to be at the bottom, though when I do this there is a white space to the left that is ~10px [which looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sQoZ.png), identical to the default browser padding that should have already been disabled to start with. Nothing I do makes this spacing go away.

The home page has no problems with the footer, so I don't understand what's breaking the footer.

Relevant code:

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="parPlaceholder">stuff</div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="footerStuff">footer placeholder thing</div>
      </div> 

.footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  display: grid;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  align-content: center;
}
.footerStuff {
  margin: 10px 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The white space is being caused by the default browser styles on the body. This can be fixed by overwritting them with the style below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```